# uBlock Chrome extension unenables at every startup

Tags: google-chrome

How come? I need to enable it manually every time I reboot my computer.

Ubuntu 14.04, Gnome 3 DE

Comment: Have you been runing graphical user apps with sudo?

Comment: Can you give examples? What could it be?

Comment: From where did you install uBlock? If it's from the Chrome store, the extension package is signed to guarantee its content cannot be modified. I believe if the package is modified -- i.e. if the signature in the package does no longer match the content -- Chrome will disable it automatically.